# Xcode 5 ios app submission errors using application loader

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5, store

I am trying to submit my first app to the iOS app store (using Xcode 5.0.2 i believe) but when i used application loader 2.9 i received the following four errors.

*Apple's web service operation was not successful*

*Unable to authenticate the package:*

*ERROR ITMS-:"No.app bundels found in the package" at SoftwareAssets/SoftwareAsset 
(MZitmspSoftwareAssetPackage)*

*Could not start delivery: all transports failed diagnostics*

Maybe I did not zip something right but I am absolutely stumped.Is there something wrong with my bundle id or app id? Anyone help would be grealy appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not using a build server, better to just use Xcode's Archive option. Archive the build, then use the Organizer to submit the app.

Comment: it is perfect answer follow  it

Comment: This is the solution to the problem. I had archive problems but those were because of armv7s. Thanks a lot, guys.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm doing, I get this error after archiving with XCode and submitting via Organizer...